# Trying to store a pointer to an object in a member variable

Tags: c++

I am still new to c++, and i encountered a problem which I can't seem to solve. I tried to create a simplified version I have an abstract class of which i have a derived class. In another class i am trying to save a pointer (type abstract class).

abstract.h

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Abstract
{
protected:
    double x;

public:
    Abstract(double x)
    {
        x = x;
    }

    virtual double getX() = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Abstract> clone() const = 0;
};
```

derived.h

```
#include "abstract.h"
#include <iostream>

class Derived : public Abstract
{
public:
    Derived(double x) : Abstract(x){};
    ~Derived() { std::cout << "im dead" << std::endl; }
    double getX() override;
    std::unique_ptr<Abstract> clone() const;
};
```

derived.cpp

```
#include "derived.h"
#include <iostream>

std::unique_ptr<Abstract> Derived::clone() const
{
    return std::make_unique<Derived>(*this);
}

double Derived::getX()
{
    return x;
}
```

a.h

```
#include <memory>
#include "abstract.h"
#include <list>
class A
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Abstract> abstract;

public:
    A(){};

    void receive(double x);
    void print();
};
```

a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
#include "abstract.h"
#include "derived.h"
#include <iostream>

void A::receive(double x)
{
    abstract = (new Derived(x))->clone();
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

void A::print()
{
    std::cout << abstract->getX() << std::endl;
}
```

My main.cpp looks like this

```
#include "a.h"
int main()
{
    A a{};
    a.receive(2.0);
    a.print();
}
```

It should print 2.0 but it just returns 0. I have got the feeling i am missing something fundamental about pointers in c++. But i have not found any information on this behavior online.

I have also tried without smart pointers but the same result.

Comment: `A::abstract` should be a unique_ptr, otherwise in `A::receive` you are putting a unique_ptr into a shared_ptr, which may cause your issue. Try make in a unique_ptr, and use move constractor instead of assignment operator when calling `Derived(x)->clone()`

Comment: dont  call `new` and not store the returned pointer. Basically, never call `new`

Comment: This won't work:  Abstract(double x)  {  x = x;  } . Instead: Abstract(double x_)  {  x = x_;  }

Comment: `receive()` leaks the memory you (shouldn't have) `new`ed.

Comment: You shouldn't use `clone()` at all in `received`. Just set either `abstract = std::make_unique(x);` or even better: `*abstract = x;`. No need to reassign the pointer since you only want to set the value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments which helped me find the answer. @Niels Holst, your comment made my code work and @Faraenor your comments made my code better.

In the end I ditched the clone method and modified my code to

abstract constructor

```
Abstract(double x_)
    {
        x = x_;
    }
```

and A::receive

```
void A::receive(double x)
{
    abstract = std::make_unique<Derived>(x);
}
```

This works well and I believe I took care of the other issues mentioned in the comments. Thanks guys :)